# Get company information from exact online API

Tags: reporting, exact-online

I have a task to create quarterly reports for our companies that show some basic information in a graph such as sales per quarter, profit / loss compared to last year, open sales and open costs.

I though about scheduling a cron job for AWS Lambda for every quarter to fetch all the companies from exact, generate a pdf report and send it to the companies. Problem is that I can't seem to find the correct API endpoints for any of these things.

My question is, if it's possible to get all that kind of data using exact api so I can display it correctly in a graph in a report? I know that exact crunches the numbers from all of the invoices and provides them in a graph, but even if I manage to get all of the data from Exact api, will it be correct by default or I will need to manually add / subtract different invoices, calculate VAT etc.

First time user of exact, sorry if the question is too vague.

Comment: You are probably looking for the XML API Balances. See https://documentation.invantive.com for BalanceLinrsPerPerjkd. It has very low API consumption compared to the ExactOnlineRest counterpart. In general no post-processing is necessary. Direct access from Lambda can be challenging. We use our own proxy invantive cloud for this.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I am having a very hard time understanding how exact api relationships work. I used ReportingBalance API Endpoint (https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=FinancialReportingBalance) to retrieve some data for the current year of a company, however when I compare it to the actual graph within exact online, the numbers don't realy match. Fetching the data from the api gives me the raw data I guess, while Exact processes it. 
Do you have any suggestions how to get just the overview data of each company for the reports?

Comment: The entity relationship diagram can be found at https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online/Exact%20Online%20API%20Data%20Model.pdf as PDF. ReportingBalance should match Exact, but maybe need to exclude some specific types like 310 (opening balance from top of head). I would recommend using BalanceLinesPerPeriod (Exact Online XML API); it has many advantages. ReportingBalances is not so very well designed.

Comment: @GuidoLeenders I don't find BalanceLinesPerPeriod in exact API documentation, only in invantive docs. Is that a 3rd party service that integrates with exact? As far as I see invantive has a base price of 60 eur/m + a minimum of 0.6 eur per managed company / month. That is overkill for reports once every quarter.

Comment: Please look at the XML documentation, not at the REST documentation. It is the topic named Balances. 
The schema is "XML" on https://documentation.invantive.com/2017R2/exact-online-data-model/webhelp/exact-online-connector-exactonlinexml-xml-balancelinesperperiod.html?q=balancelinesperperiod. Below there are lines, periods, etc.